# Why is calculating function runtime returning 0 seconds using time.h

Tags: c, time.h

I am trying to use time.h to solve for 4 functions runtimes, but my output is returning 0.000000 sec

```
double timep[4] = {0.0};

clock_t begin, end;

begin = clock();
function1();
end = clock();
timep[0] = (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

begin = clock();
function2();
end = clock();
timep[1] = (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

begin = clock();
function3();
end = clock();
timep[2] = (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

begin = clock();
funtion4();
end = clock();
timep[3] = (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
```

Printing the timep array using (%lf) yields

```
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
0.000000
```

Comment: What about printing the raw `begin` and `end` values?

Comment: Does your function do anything?

Comment: About how long do the functions actually take?

Comment: Try printing with `%g` instead of `%f`.

Comment: Clock() has very low precision. It's likely that your function executes in time shorter than a single click

Comment: functions are very short. If I manually cause the program to wait, the correct time is outputted. however, for some reason the output is rounded, example 1.654000 is outputted if I manually cause the functions to wait.

Comment: Because your functions are so fast.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may just be that the functions are relatively fast, combined with the fact the clock often has a minimum resolution (in that it's usually a multiple of some value, supported by your comment that "for some reason the output is rounded, example 1.654000").

A better way to check may be to time *many* iterations of the function (assuming no side effects that would affect later runs) and divide the total time by the count, something like:

```c
#define QUANT 1000
begin = clock();
for (int i = 0; i < QUANT; ++i)
    function1();
end = clock();
timep[0] = (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC / QUANT;
```

This will amortise the errors that may be produced by the afore-mentioned resolution of the clock. A potential error of (for example) +/- 1ms has far less impact on an operation that take 1000ms (the loop of a thousand calls) than one that takes 1ms (a single call).

The latter could give you any value from 0 to 2ms (+/- 100%), the former 999 to 1001ms (+/- 0.1%).